# simplexml_load_file PHP não funciona de jeito nenhum

Tags: php

(Estou usando Ubuntu)

Eu tentei de tudo que eu imaginei que fosse o problema. Tentei primeiro usando o site que eu quero recolher o XML que é de qualquer canal do Youtube.

**Falhou...**

Depois tentei baixando ele e em seguida colocando na pasta do servidor pra ver se mudava alguma coisa.

**Falhou...**

Olhei se meu php.ini estava com **allow_url_fopen = On**, e sim, estava **On**.

É sempre o mesmo erro. Ele entrega no console do navegador o **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**, não importa, se o arquivo existe, ou não.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que está acontecendo?

Comment: Se o erro 500 for originado no seu servidor veja os logs.

Comment: Você sabe onde encontra esses logs no Ubuntu?

Comment: Dê um `php -i | grep 'log'`, ele deve listar os caminhos do logs. Procure também no Apache/Nginx (no caso do Apache geralmente é `/var/log/apache2/error.log`). Mas, isso depende se este erro está sendo *gerado* pelo seu servidor ou pelo servidor que quer se conectar, do modo que estar a pergunta parece que quem gera tal erro é o YouTube e não você.

Comment: Isso não acontece só quando tento conectar com o arquivo do Youtube, acontece com qualquer arquivo de qualquer lugar, até mesmo dentro do servidor. Já tentei também Deviantart, sites de noticias, sempre da a mesma coisa.

E o erro apenas está presente neste comando.

Eu consegui chegar no log, e o error foi este aqui:
 Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_file() in /var/www/html/test/index3.php:41\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/test/index3.php on line 41, referer: http://[IP_HIDE]/test/index3.php

Comment: Você não tem o XML instalado, dê um `apt install php7.0-mbstring php7.0-zip php7.0-xml`, por exemplo, veja isto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593521/php-7-simplexml.

Comment: Deu certo. Agradeço muito pela sua ajuda. Se puder, coloque isso como resposta para eu encerrar o tópico com todos os créditos a você :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Também havia tentado de tudo, só funcionava localhost, no server dava o mesmo erro. Tentei esta dica que estava pequeno no comentário acima e funcionou:

```
apt install php7.0-mbstring php7.0-zip php7.0-xml
```

Obrigado!!